# how to display long binary or nchar value in TDengine taos shell

Tags: tdengine

In TDengine taos shell, if the length of a binary/nchar type is more than 60, it will be cut, how to make it fully displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add \G in the tail of your command.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you need to pay attention to the length of the field. Binary type should not store non ASCII characters, otherwise there may be display problems.